# Variable number of subreports on FastReport .NET

Tags: c#, .net, fastreport

I have a report that prints the information a sell. The report's  Data Source is a SellReport object.

Now I want to print the information of more than one sell, but not of a fixed number of sells. I think the best way is to pass a Collection as Data Source and for each SellReport of the collection it generates a subreport.

Anyone know how to create subreports dynamically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is example, how to create a report using code

```
Report report = new Report();



// register the "Products" table

 report.RegisterData(dataSet1.Tables["Products"], "Products");

// enable it to use in a report

 report.GetDataSource("Products").Enabled = true;



// create A4 page with all margins set to 1cm

ReportPage page1 = new ReportPage();

 page1.Name = "Page1";

 report.Pages.Add(page1);



// create ReportTitle band

 page1.ReportTitle = new ReportTitleBand();

 page1.ReportTitle.Name = "ReportTitle1";

// set its height to 1.5cm

 page1.ReportTitle.Height = Units.Centimeters * 1.5f;



// create group header

GroupHeaderBand group1 = new GroupHeaderBand();

 group1.Name = "GroupHeader1";

 group1.Height = Units.Centimeters * 1;

// set group condition

 group1.Condition = "[Products.ProductName].Substring(0, 1)";

// add group to the page.Bands collection

 page1.Bands.Add(group1);



// create group footer

 group1.GroupFooter = new GroupFooterBand();

 group1.GroupFooter.Name = "GroupFooter1";

 group1.GroupFooter.Height = Units.Centimeters * 1;



// create DataBand

DataBand data1 = new DataBand();

 data1.Name = "Data1";

 data1.Height = Units.Centimeters * 0.5f;

// set data source

 data1.DataSource = report.GetDataSource("Products");

// connect databand to a group

 group1.Data = data1;



// create "Text" objects



// report title

TextObject text1 = new TextObject();

 text1.Name = "Text1";

// set bounds

 text1.Bounds = new RectangleF(0, 0, 

   Units.Centimeters * 19, Units.Centimeters * 1);

// set text

 text1.Text = "PRODUCTS";

// set appearance

 text1.HorzAlign = HorzAlign.Center;

 text1.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 14, FontStyle.Bold);

// add it to ReportTitle

 page1.ReportTitle.Objects.Add(text1);



// group

TextObject text2 = new TextObject();

 text2.Name = "Text2";

 text2.Bounds = new RectangleF(0, 0, 

   Units.Centimeters * 2, Units.Centimeters * 1);

 text2.Text = "[[Products.ProductName].Substring(0, 1)]";

 text2.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold);

// add it to GroupHeader

 group1.Objects.Add(text2);



// data band

TextObject text3 = new TextObject();

 text3.Name = "Text3";

 text3.Bounds = new RectangleF(0, 0, 

   Units.Centimeters * 10, Units.Centimeters * 0.5f);

 text3.Text = "[Products.ProductName]";

 text3.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 8);

// add it to DataBand

 data1.Objects.Add(text3);



// group footer

TextObject text4 = new TextObject();

 text4.Name = "Text4";

 text4.Bounds = new RectangleF(0, 0, 

   Units.Centimeters * 10, Units.Centimeters * 0.5f);

 text4.Text = "Count: [CountOfProducts]";

 text4.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 8, FontStyle.Bold);

// add it to GroupFooter

 group1.GroupFooter.Objects.Add(text4);



// add a total

Total groupTotal = new Total();

 groupTotal.Name = "CountOfProducts";

 groupTotal.TotalType = TotalType.Count;

 groupTotal.Evaluator = data1;

 groupTotal.PrintOn = group1.Footer;

// add it to report totals

 report.Dictionary.Totals.Add(groupTotal);

 // run the report

 report.Show();
```

And example for Data Source:

```
  private int[] FArray;
 / create report instance
      Report report = new Report();

      / register the array
      report.RegisterData(FArray, "Array");
```

You can use a list instead of int[]

And look at example \Demos\C#\DataFromBusinessObject

Comment: When i run this , it gives me error saying `(Function): Error CS1061: 'FastReport.ReportTitleBand' does not contain a definition for 'Functions' and no extension method 'Functions' accepting a first argument of type 'FastReport.ReportTitleBand' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` , @Gromozeka  can you please look at this ReportTitleBand.

Comment: Assemblies that i have added are `using FastReport; using FastReport.Data; using FastReport.Web; using FastReport.Utils; using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Data; using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;`